# jQuery hover only works in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser, hover

I have an issue with hovers. They work fine in IE, but not Mozilla Firefox or Chrome. I'm guessing it's because it's rather vague, every td but for now that's what I need. Here's the fiddle (not working) http://jsfiddle.net/233qG/ Thanks in advance.

**The HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="modalPop">Modal Information</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
div.modalPop
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:8px;
    background-color:white;
    margin: 280px 50px 0 0;
    z-index: 9999;
}
a.modalPop:hover + div.modalPop
{
    display:block;
}
div.modalPop:hover
{
    display:block;
}
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').hover(
      function(){$('.modalPop' + this).stop().hide().fadeIn('slow');},
      function(){$('.modalPop' + this).stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');}
    );  
});
```

Comment: `$('.modalPop' + this)` ??? adding an element to a string. I'm suprised it works anywhere ?

Comment: I don't see a `a.modalPop` element...

Comment: Have you even looked at your console errors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$('.modalPop' + this)` is invalid. `this` is an object. You are trying to concat a string with an object. Just use `$('.modalPop')`

If you open on the console(chrome tools or firebug) you should see an error like this:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .modalPop[object HTMLTableCellElement]

Frankly, I don't see why it is even working in IE. Why are you adding `this` to the string?

Answer (score 1):

I think You mean something like this:

```
$('td').hover(
  function(){$('.modalPop').stop().hide().fadeIn('slow').html("Modal Information : " + $(this).text());},
  function(){$('.modalPop').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');}
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/233qG/3/